# How do I detect in my class component which input value's clicked in functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

How do I detect in my class component which `<input/>`'s `value` was clicked in my functional component?  For example, if the user clicks `Yes`, then I want the `postIsClicked()` (which's in my class component) function to display that it's indeed detected the `Yes` that's been clicked.

My attempt consisted of giving a `name` to the inputs and then trying to detect is via `e.target.name` but it just keeps loggin `No has been clicked` in the console regardless of which button I press (Yes or No)

What am I doing wrong?

Pastebin below.

https://pastebin.com/tWNM16p3

Comment: I think you're missing some of your code in pastebin. There's no console log that says `/*...*/ has been clicked`

Comment: @StevenWexler oops!! wrong one. I just posted the right pastebin now.

Comment: I recommend trying `console.log(props.name)` in your imagePreview component. I suspect you're not passing in `name` as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` function can receive the event as argument, so you can access the value by getting `e.target.value`.

In your case you just need to receive `event` as argument to `postIsClicked(event)` and then `console.log("clicked" + event.target.value)`